# Power Shell Script - Object Oriented Programming

Tags: powershell

I've been having some issues trying to pass along some variables with the needed output I need.

Summary, I need to grab the CPU utilization of multiple PC, memory of those PC, and HDD usage, I would like the information to come out with what the PC name is followed by each other category of information required listed above.

Below is what I have so far, however, I cant figure out why I cant get the PCName to output for the CPU utilization. The hdd command is working well but I'm stuck trying to string everything together through objects. Thanks for any help.

### CPU Script

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path ()

foreach ($computer in $computers)

$CPUAvg = (get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% 
Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |    select -ExpandProperty countersamples | 
select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average)

Write-Output $CPUAvg
```

### Cant Figure out how to output CPUName for each computer in $computers

### HDD Script works fine

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path ()
Get−CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | where{$_.DriveType −eq '3'} `
| Select DeviceID, DriveType,VolumeName,
@{N='TotalSize(GB)';E={[Math]::Ceiling($_.Size/1GB)}}, @{N='FreeSize(GB)';E= 
{[Math]::Ceiling($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}} |ft −AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

currently the code always queries the local data and not that one from a remote computer. None of the samples gives the information from the variable $computers back.

In your first sample the foreach statement is missing its expression ({}). But you do not need to loop, as get-counter supports arrays for the parameter "-computername":

```
get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 -computername $computers
```

you get objects back which contain an attribute called CounterSamples, the value contains the computername.

in case of your 2nd sample, you have to specify the parameter "-computername" to specify a list of computers to connect to. also you can do the filtering one step earlier - e.g.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path [path]
$result = Get-CimInstance -query "Select DeviceId,DriveType,VolumeName,SystemName from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3" -ComputerName $computers |  Select-Object SystemName,DeviceID,DriveType,VolumeName,@{N='TotalSize(GB)';E={[Math]::Ceiling($_.Size/1GB)}}, @{N='FreeSize(GB)';E={[Math]::Ceiling($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}}
```

The variable $result contains the information. you can now output the information, like in your sample, only on the screen (ft -Autosize). or you can export it into a csv/json:

```
#as csv
$result | export-csv C:\my.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
#as json
$result | convertto-json | set-content C:\my.json -Encoding:utf8
```

You could also use the invoke-command cmdlet to connect to the remote computers ,query the information and build and return a object containing the necessary information:

```
$code = {
    #Query cpu Info
    $counter = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5
    $processorTimeAvg = ($counter.countersamples.cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    #Query Disk Info
    $diskInfo = Get-CimInstance -query "Select DeviceId,DriveType,VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3" |  Select-Object DeviceID,DriveType,VolumeName,@{N='TotalSize(GB)';E={[Math]::Ceiling($_.Size/1GB)}}, @{N='FreeSize(GB)';E={[Math]::Ceiling($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}} 
    #Build Object to return
    $attrsht = @{
        computerName=$env:Computername
        processorTimeAvg=$processorTimeAvg
        deviceId=$diskInfo.DeviceId
        driveType=$diskInfo.driveType
        volumeName=$diskInfo.volumeName
        'totalSize(GB)'=$diskInfo.'totalSize(GB)'
        'freeSize(GB)'=$diskInfo.'freeSize(GB)'
    }
    return New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
}
#Get list of computers
$computers = Get-Content [path]
#Query Computers 
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $code
#Export result to json
$result | ConvertTo-Json | set-content C:\my.json -Encoding:utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything works except when a server has two HDD, the code will not output two separate lines of info.

```
$code = {
#Query cpu Info
$counter = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5
$processorTimeAvg = ($counter.countersamples.cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).Average

#Query Disk Info
$diskInfo = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | where{$_.DriveType -eq '3'} | Select-Object -Property DeviceID, @{'Name' = 'Size (GB)'; Expression={[Math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB,2)}},@{'Name' = 'FreeSpace (GB)'; Expression={[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1GB,2)}}

#Build Object to return
$attrsht = @{
    computerName=$env:Computername
    processorTimeAvg=$processorTimeAvg
    diskinfo=$diskInfo
}
return New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
}

#Get list of computers
$computers = Get-Content -Path 

#Query Computers 
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $code

#Export result to SAD Folder 
$result | Export-Csv -Path
```